# Posgresql não tem nenhum role com superuser como criar uma

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Quando fui verificar no postgresql não tem nenhum superuser como eu faço para alterar ou criar um superuser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757431/postgres-upgrade-a-user-to-be-a-superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criar usuario:

```
CREATE USER myuser;
CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD ‘mypassword‘;
```

referência: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-createuser.html

Para Alterar:

```
  ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757486/7920143

Via Pgadmin link do Youtube abaixo:

video: https://youtu.be/niAYrTLGFvk

Comment: Adiciona também ai como realmente atribui privilegios para o user: `grant all privileges on database dbname to dbuser;`

Comment: Quando tento alterar aparece a seguinte mensagem.

ERRO:  deve ser super-usuário para criar super-usuários


********** Error **********

ERRO: deve ser super-usuário para criar super-usuários
SQL state: 42501

Comment: Como você esta tentando utilizar o comando; Existe no banco um usario chamando postgres, você tem que logar com ele; Tanto no psql quanto no PgadminIII ou 4;

Se for pelo Pgadmin faça uma conexão com usuario postgres,

se o usuario postgres não tiver senha você vai ter que abrir o psql e digitar ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'; você loga com ele e altera a senha do seu usuario sem problemas! No video do youtube lá ta ensinando.

Comment: CREATE ROLE pgsql with password '@123'
superuser createdb createrole replication;

Comment: Nem o usuario postgres está como superuser

Comment: Não pode ser por padrão ele é o super do super:
 postgres     | Super-usuário, Cria role, Cria BD, Replicação, Ignora RLS | {}

Comment: Acessa o psql e digita \du e posta na pergunta

Comment: Lista de roles
 Nome da role |               Atributos               | Membro de
--------------+---------------------------------------+----------
 autosystem   |                                       | {}
 distro       |                                       | {}
 postgres     | Cria role, Cria BD, ReplicaþÒo        | {}
 pqsql        | Super-usußrio, NÒo pode efetuar login | {}

Comment: O usuário existe você ta usando que OS?

Comment: O comando que você tem que digitar é só esse

ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'postgres'

E fazer sua conexão com usuario postgres e criar quantos usuarios você quiser.

Lá no pgadmin3 voce consegue conectar depois de criar uma senha.

Comment: esta com o windows 7, lá consegue logar no pgadmin como o usuario mas não consegue criar nenhum usuario com permissões de superuser

Comment: @DanielAlencarSouza abra o Pgadmin3 crie uma conexão com o user postgres como vocễ mostrou ele tem permissão;  depois vá Login Roles Clique com o direito(botão de menu) Criar New Login Role, la navegue nas abas, role name o nome do usuario, password, em "Role Previlege" Marque superuser a regra que você quiser;

Comment: O user Postgres está sem a permissão de superuser achei um superuser pqsql porém não tem permissão de logar. acessei com o postgres e rodei o script "alter user pqsql login"; mas diz que não tem permissão de superuser para alterar

Comment: Uma coisa é o usuário postgres no OS, outro no bd. Se você  esta logado com o usuario postgres no windows abra o cmd como admin, 

   psql -d postgres -U postgres psql
   ALTER USER postgres with PASSWORD 'minha_senha';
   \q